# warnings during uninstallation of a package which contains .tmp files on redhat 7

Tags: redhat, uninstallation, rpm, rpmbuild

I have created a package which has .tmp file. During unistallation of that package on red hat 7, I am getting warnings as below.

`# rpm -e package_name
warning: file file_loc/abc.tmp: remove failed: No such file or directory`

But, on other releases of REDHAT Linux, I didn't received this error.

Comment: Before you remove the package does that file exist? Does `rpm -V package_name` indicate everything is consistent and correct before you remove the package?

Comment: it's been showing that the file abc.tmp is missing. Eventhough it is missing, i didn't received any warnings on previous versions of red hat.

Comment: Then it sounds like the newer version of rpm in RH7 added that as a warning to me. Seems like a reasonable warning to have I suppose.